# Microsoft bot framework - Returns 502 error from task/fetch

Tags: node.js, botframework, chatbot, microsoft-teams, adaptive-cards

I have an MS Teams adapter written using the botframeworks sdk v4 for node js which works perfectly for normal conversations. But when I try to do a task/fetch, it returns an error message "Unable to reach app. Please try again." on the task module popup
[Unable to reach app. Please try again.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5wUtM.png)
[502 error messages unable to invoke](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EhiEn.png)

Comment: you are doing any long running operation or debug the app ?

Comment: I'm not doing any debug operation., when i was opening a modal popup window from bot section(type: "task/fetch") i'm getting this error.

Comment: then may be some settings issue to send back the result to team

Comment: We are not able to repro the issue at our end. Could you please check when you are opening a task module are you able to get the event in backend? Could you please conform?

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/EhiEn.png ,https://i.stack.imgur.com/5wUtM.png check this link for a reference when I'm clicking a login from bot section that time getting this error

Comment: Are You using any CSP headers in your code? Also Could you please share your app manifest with us?

Comment: now it is working fine... because I didn't added a ** handleTeamsTaskModuleFetch ** server side action inside bot section.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posting the Answer for better knowledge

Copying from @siva subramanian comments

Added a ** handleTeamsTaskModuleFetch ** server side action inside bot section.